# Mostrar mais que um valor da coluna do dropdown C#

Tags: c#, sql, dropdown

Como poderia mostrar mais que o valor de um coluna de um dropdown?

Tentei o seguinte método:

```
private void BindDropDownList()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string localidade = string.Empty;
        string distrito = string.Empty;
        string newName = string.Empty;

        SqlConnection connection;
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM [Moradas] WHERE ([IDUser] = @IDUser)";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            sqlDa.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    localidade = dt.Rows[i]["Localidade"].ToString();
                    distrito = dt.Rows[i]["Distrito"].ToString();
                    newName = localidade + " ---- " + distrito;
                    ddlMoradaSecd.Items.Add(new ListItem(newName, localidade));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Fetch Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Sem o `WHERE` funciona correcto, mas eu necessito do `WHERE`, para apenas mostrar as moradas daquele utilizador, preciso de um `WHERE` com `sessionparameter` e `sessionfield`, tal como estou a utilizar no `sqldatasource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceMoradaSecd" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Moradas] WHERE ([IDUser] = @IDUser) ORDER BY [Morada]">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="IDUser" SessionField="IDUtilizador" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Qual erro está ocorrendo? Aparentemente seu código está certo.

Comment: O erro é que falta a variavel escalar @IDUser

Answer (score 1):

Minha sugestão é que ao instanciar cada `dropDownListItem` em `new ListItem(newName, localidade)` você passe para o campo valor do item não apenas a localidade, mas também o ID do usuário, concatenado com a localidade, separados por um espaço em branco. Mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    localidade = dt.Rows[i]["Localidade"].ToString();
    distrito = dt.Rows[i]["Distrito"].ToString();
    newName = localidade + " ---- " + distrito;

    // Obtém o ID do usuário.
    string idUsuario = dt.Rows[i]["IDUser"].ToString();

    // Coloca no campo valor de cada item a localidade e o id do usuário, 
    // separados por um espaço em branco.
    ddlMoradaSecd.Items.Add(new ListItem(newName, string.Concat(localidade, " ", idUsuario)));
}
```

Tendo feito isso, o próximo passo é alterar na página *.aspx o comando `SELECT` para extrair o id do usuário que está armazenado no campo valor do item. Como o valor do dropDownList é agora a concatenação de `localidade + " " + idDoUsuário`, então o ID do usuário é o valor após o espaço em branco, e pode ser obtido da seguinte maneira:

```
SUBSTRING (@ValorDoDropDownListItem, CHARINDEX ( ' ', @ValorDoDropDownListItem ), LEN(@ValorDoDropDownListItem))
```

Com essa alteração o SqlDtaSource ficará então algo semelhante a isso:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceMoradaSecd" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Moradas] WHERE ([IDUser] = 
SUBSTRING (@ValorDoDropDownListItem, CHARINDEX ( ' ', @ValorDoDropDownListItem ), LEN(@ValorDoDropDownListItem))) 
ORDER BY [Morada]">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="ValorDoDropDownListItem" SessionField="ValorDoDropDownListItem" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Naturalmente, é necessário também alterar o `DropDownList` no *.aspx para modificar o nome do parâmetro de forma que corresponda com o `@ValorDoDropDownListItem` que estou sugerindo nessa resposta.

Outro ponto importante a observar é que, se você usar essa solução, você deve fazer ainda outro tratamento quando for utilizar o valor do `dropDownListItem` selecionado para extrair o valor da localidade. Quando você for utilizar esse valor, por exemplo em algum postback no code-behind, você deverá fazer o seguinte para obter a localidade:

```
// Lembrando que o valor dos itens é localidade + " " + idUsuário,
// a localidade corresponde então ao texto que está antes do espaço
// em branco no valor de cada item.
var localidade = valorDoItemSelecionado.Split(' ')[0];
```